# How to avoid the program to read past the end of input file?

Tags: while-loop, pascal, eof

This **Pascal** code keep attempting to read past the end of input file. Why this could be happened? How to fix this?

```
program wwhilencounter;
var 
  bil,jumlah : integer;
begin
  jumlah := 0;
  while not eof(input) do
  begin
    readln(bil);
    jumlah:=jumlah+bil;
  end;
  writeln(jumlah);
  readln 
end.
```

Comment: What's wrong with the program? If you type in some numbers, each followed by Enter, and then press Ctrl-D (linux) or Ctrl-Z (Windows) you get the sum then it waits for you to press Enter to quit the program. It seems to work as designed. What "file" are you talking about? This is reading from the standard input, not a file. The standard input is open again for the last `readln`. Why are you asking about avoiding this?

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop reads until the end of the input, but then you have another `readln` just before the end of the program.  You've already run out of input by this point.